# Avoiding formatting in blank cells

Tags: excel

this is my first post and a newb at Excel.

I did a few date formulas with conditional formatting and realised after that the formatting is being applied to all the blanks cells as well.

Is there an easy edit I can add to the existing formulas i wrote or do I have to start again?

Formulas below :

```
=AND($D2>TODAY(),$D2-TODAY()<=7)

=$D2<TODAY()

=$D2=TODAY()
```

Comment: You can try `=IF($D2<>"",$D2<TODAY(),FALSE)`.

Comment: How do I add that in my formulas ? Using AND like this =AND($D2>TODAY(),$D2-TODAY()<=7,$D2<>"") let me try

Comment: Something like `=IF($D2<>"",AND($D2>TODAY(),$D2-TODAY()<=7),FALSE)`.

Comment: Yes it worked do you mind posting it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `IF()` function to detect either it empty or not. Then apply formula if it is not empty. By default excel empty/blank cell is determine as `0` zero when you are comparing with number values. Dates are nothing but number value. So, to avoiding blank cells in conditional formatting use `IF()` function like-

```
=IF($D2<>"",AND($D2>TODAY(),$D2-TODAY()<=7),FALSE)
```